# c# is it necessary to new up object

Tags: c#-4.0

Scenario:

Lets say I've a Person class. I also have GetPersonDetail function on one of the Helper class.

So is it necessary to new up the Person class or is it ok to do as below.

```
Person person=null;

person= Helper.GetPersonDetail();

OR

Person person = new Person();
person=Helper.GetPersonDetail();
```

Both seems to work, just wondering if there are any unexpected consequences of the option one above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new object before getting it from the method. The object that you created will just be thrown away when you assign the result of the method to the variable, so creating an object first is just a waste.

Normally nothing harmful happens from creating an instance in vain, but if it needs some cleanup before being removed (for example disposing), it wont happen for that instance.